# Is this abestos glue/ do these tiles contain abestos, if so how can I safely remove/work around it?

Tags: safety, adhesive

After taking up vinyl tiles I found this thick
Brown sludgy adhesive.  Is this abestos glue/does it contain abestos?  Do the vinyl tiles contain abestos?

If so and I vacuum the glue with a hepa vacuum will the abestos be gone?  If not what can I do to safely work around the abestos while removing or covering the tiles? If the tiles contain abestos, will pusshing/snapping them out of place release the abestos or not in which case its safe to do so?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the glue has asbestos but the tiles do normally contain asbestos. The glue was a tar / asphalt based product I have removed some in the ancient past using mineral spirits and other solvents like acetone and MEK , but acetone and MEK are really harsh chemicals and today I don’t recommend them.
Read up on the MSDS OR safety data sheets as they are called today prior to using so you understand the risks.

Comment: You can send a sample of the tile for testing. As noted, there's a high chance of asbestos. Don't do anything with the tiles that will release dust (sand/grind/etc).

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate so its its ok to just push/snap the tiles out and discard them without any danger of inhaling abestos?

Comment: @JamesWilson No, it’s not ok to disturb the tiles without any danger of inhaling asbestos. If the tiles are asbestos then it’s highly likely the mastic is too. Do not scrape the floor without proper preparation. I’d test both the tiles and mastic. If the tiles are 9” square, then it’s highly likely it’s asbestos. There’s many videos on “how to”, but I’d check EPA rules on proper manner for removal and disposal.

Comment: Agree that snapping tiles has a high probability of releasing asbestos if present.

Comment: almost all of the tiles I had tested were 12x 12 or maybe slightly under.  the glue I did have tested did not have asbestos but fragments from the tile in the glue would , the last batch I wasted $ on testing was new in 1980 it contained asbestos but the glue was a latex base and it did not have asbestos either.  Today I consider all of those tiles to contain asbestos why waste the $ on testing when just about everything in this class had asbestos.

Comment: Guys, I asked this question too late.  We had already snapped a number of tiles and scraped some glue.  Does it mean we very likely have abestos in our lungs and this could cause severe illness?

Comment: I would not worry about it, yes asbestos can cause severe health problems but many worked there entire lives in the industry with no problems, my exposure of around 50 years has not had any known negative health problems, however with that said I have been involved with probably 1000 jobs without  so much as a dust mask until we understood the hazards. Could your slight exposure cause problems? You probably have a better chance of getting struck by lightning, maybe even twice.