# Does white vinegar over asphalt cause any harmful reaction?

Tags: safety, adhesive

I previously asked a question about which glue is under my vinyl tiles and the answer said it was tar/asphalt.
[Is this abestos glue/ do these tiles contain abestos, if so how can I safely remove/work around it?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/191439/is-this-abestos-glue-do-these-tiles-contain-abestos-if-so-how-can-i-safely-rem)

Today I wanted to disinfect the area as there were a lot of dead maggots under there and I sprayed all the glue down with a concentrated amount of white vinegar.  I don't know why I always do this.

It could be my imagination or my medical issues as I'm sensitive but it made me feel very unwell.  The glue before the vinegar was making me unwell.

Maybe this is better suited to the chemistry site but does any reaction take place with white vinegar and these glues which lead to harmful toxins to be emitted?

Thanks

Comment: White vinegar is an acid - can react with anything it is in contact with... so define every material you put in contact with the vinegar then do your chemical reactions.

Comment: James don’t forget to upvote and or accept answers you have quite a few with multiple answers but not many accepted.

Comment: "*Does white vinegar over asphalt cause any harmful reaction*"  I don't know but it makes it taste better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the exact makeup of the glue, it would be difficult, impossible, to say with any degree of certainty, what toxins would be emitted. Most of the glues out there say to use in well ventilated areas so after years, if you spray them with an acidic compound that partially soften them up or dissolves them, they're going to be able to give off fumes. Breathing misted white vinegar can cause lung irritation especially if you have lung problems to begin with. There are also disinfectants on the market which are better than vinegar.

Comment: I would agree that the acid could interact , past cleaning agents residue could also be a cause.